# Why do Unit Test systems include useless assertive methods?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, build-automation

I'm wondering why unittest systems like [PHPUnit include what seems to be repetitive operators](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions) that just add overhead to the unit tests. I can understand a couple of those methods, but most seem like a total waste of time.

```
public function testPop(array stack)
{
    this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop(stack));
    this->assertEmpty(stack);
}
```

vs raw code (which is shorter and faster)

```
public function testPop(array stack)
{
    this->assert('foo' == array_pop(stack));
    this->assert(empty(stack));
}
```

Are these methods here for just so people that don't understand the language they are programming in can still write unit-tests? I'm sure the authors of this projects are smarter than myself so there must be a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions usually give more useful output. For example, an `assertEquals` test could tell you the expected and actual values, and that they were not equal.

For example, the following code:

```
this->assertEquals(1, 0);
```

Will produce this output:

```
Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1.
```

Comment: Ah, this is the reason. Interception of assertions for explanations of results.

Answer (score 2):

It's also about verbosity. This:

```
this->assert(foo == array_pop(stack));
```

Is much less verbose than:

```
this->assertEqual(foo, array_pop(stack));
```

Or even better:

```
$popped_value = array_pop(stack);
this->assertEqual($popped_value, foo);
```

In other frameworks (such as .NET's NUnit), it gets even better:

```
Assert.AreEqual(stack.Pop(), foo);
```

vs

```
var poppedValue = stack.Pop();
Assert.That(poppedValue, Is.EqualTo(foo));
```

Reading the last example is almost *as if somebody was explaining the code* to you. That's invaluable when you deal with old/somebody's else code.

Comment: I just assumed that the programmer already read code like `Assert(poppedValue == foo);` as `Assert.That(poppedValue, Is.EqualTo(foo));` since it's just basic conditional logic.

Comment: @Xeoncross: of course, we do that. It seems trivial now, when dealing with single line of code. Usually during programming, your brain is much more occupied than that. And that's when simple things matter - having code that (almost) *reads itself* to you - invaluable.

Comment: Yes, that I why I upvoted you. Code is read many more times than it's written - so a clear, concise code block it worth a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is afaik to be able to present cleaner messages for failing tests, compare for example;

```
Test failed: 'foo' == array_pop(stack) assertion failed
```

to

```
Test failed: foo should be 2, actual value 5.
```