# Unit testing: why is the expected argument always first in equality tests?

Tags: unit-testing

Why is it that every unit testing framework (that I know of) requires the expected value in equality tests to always be the first argument:

```
Assert.AreEqual(42, Util.GetAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything());

assertEquals(42, Util.GetAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything());
```

etc.

I'm quite used to it now, but every coder I try to teach unit testing makes the mistake of reversing the arguments, which I understand perfectly. Google didn't help, maybe one of the hard-core unit-testers here knows the answer?

Comment: Have you looked at the default error messages that are produced when a test fails?  That's why.  Or are you asking why the messages are written that way?   Are you asking about the C "standard" that worries about `if( 23 = a )` vs. `if( a = 23 )`?  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Maybe just for convenience, the assertion expression can be comparatively complex so putting the expected result first makes it easy to find.

Comment: @S.Lott: I know why I need to pass them in that order, I want to know why most unit test interfaces are written that way.

Comment: Are you asking about the C "standard" that worries about `if( 23 = a )` vs. `if( a = 23 )` and how this is echoed in unit testing?

Comment: @S.Lott: is that documented somewhere? I agree, it sounds plausible, but I haven't seen any proof of it.

Comment: What would you accept as "proof".  Sworn testimony in a court of law?

Comment: @S.Lott: I would accept that yes, but a story or interview with someone knowledgable would be fine as well.

Comment: When using rspec I find that it feels more natural to write them the other way around, for example `expect(ledger.length).to be 1`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It seems that most early frameworks used *expected* before *actual* (for some unknown reason though, dice roll perhaps?). Yet with programming languages development, and increased **fluency** of the code, that order got reversed. Most fluent interfaces usually try to mimic **natural language** and unit testing frameworks are no different.

In the assertion, we want to assure *that some object matches some conditions*. This is the natural language form, as if you were to explain your test code you'd probably say

> "In this test, I make sure that computed value is equal to 5"

instead of

> "In this test, I make sure that 5 is equal to computed value".

Difference may not be huge, but let's push it further. Consider this:

```
Assert.That(Roses, Are(Red));
```

Sounds about right. Now:

```
Assert.That(Red, Are(Roses));
```

Hm..? You probably wouldn't be too surprised if somebody told you that *roses are red*. Other way around, *red are roses*, raises suspicious questions. [Yoda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda), anybody?

[image: That doesn't sound natural at all]

*Yoda's making an important point - reversed order forces you to [think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303071/why-do-unit-test-systems-include-useless-assertive-methods/9303241#9303241).*

It gets even more *unnatural* when your assertions are more complex:

```
Assert.That(Forest, Has.MoreThan(15, Trees));
```

How would you reverse that one? *More than 15 trees are being had by forest*?

This claim (fluency as a driving factor for modification) is somehow reflected in the change that NUnit has gone through - originally ([`Assert.AreEqual`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=comparisonAsserts&r=2.2)) it used *expected* before *actual* (old style). Fluent extensions (or to use NUnit's terminology, *constraint based* - [`Assert.That`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.5.5)) reversed that order.

Comment: Not convinced that silicon-computer language is converging with meat-computer language. Code such as `y = f(x)` is not likely to morph in the direction of "Pass x to f and store the return value in y."

Answer (score 16):

I think it is just a convention now and as you said it is adopted by "every unit testing framework  (I know of)". If you are using a framework it would be annoying to switch to another framework that uses the opposite convention. So (if you are writing a new unit testing framework for example) it would be preferable for you as well to follow the existing convention.
I believe this comes from the way some developers prefer to write their equality tests:

```
if (4 == myVar)
```

To avoid any unwanted assignment, by mistake, writing one "=" instead of "==". In this case the compiler will catch this error and you will avoid a lot of troubles trying to fix a weird runtime bug.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody knows and it is the source of never ending confusions. However not all frameworks follow this pattern (to a greater confusion):

1. [**FEST-Assert**](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Fluent+Assertions+Module) uses *normal* order:

   ```
   assertThat(Util.GetAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything()).isEqualTo(42);
   ```
2. [**Hamcrest**](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/):

   ```
   assertThat(Util.GetAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything(), equalTo(42))
   ```
3. [**ScalaTest**](http://www.scalatest.org/) doesn't really make a distinction:

   ```
   Util.GetAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything() should equal (42)
   ```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know but I've been part of several animated discussions about the order of arguments to equality tests in general.

There are a lot of people who think

```
if (42 == answer) {
  doSomething();
}
```

is preferable to

```
if (answer == 42) {
  doSomething();
}
```

in C-based languages.  The reason for this is that if you accidentally put a single equals sign:

```
if (42 = answer) {
  doSomething();
}
```

will give you a compiler error, but

```
if (answer = 42) {
  doSomething();
}
```

might not, and would definitely introduce a bug that might be hard to track down.  So who knows, maybe the person/people who set up the unit testing framework were used to thinking of equality tests in this way -- or they were copying other unit testing frameworks that were already set up this way.

Comment: I was thinking this as the justification, that maybe the order of the actual equality check is easier to eyeball when the arguments match the evaluation order to the parameter order.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because JUnit was the precursor of most unit testing frameworks (not that it was the first unit testing framework, but it kicked off an explosion in unit testing). Since JUnit did it that way, all the subsequent frameworks copied this form and it became a convention.

why did JUnit do it that way? I don't know, ask Kent Beck!

Comment: Kent's answer: https://sourceforge.net/p/junit/mailman/message/3338997/

Answer (score 0):

My view for this would be to avoid any exceptions eg: 42.equals(null) vs null.equals(42)

where 42 is expected
null is actual

Comment: There could be algorithm which will output null when given 42, or output 42 when given null.

Answer (score -1):

Well they had to pick one convention. If you want to reverse it try the Hamcrest matchers. They are meant to help increase readability. Here is a basic sample:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

public HamcrestTest{
   @Test
   public void matcherShouldWork(){
       assertThat(   Math.pow( 2, 3 ),  is( 8 )  );
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how is that more readable that a plain ``assert 8 == Math.pow(2, 3)`` as you would do in py.test!

Comment: 1) you cannot confuse the order of what is the expected value versus the actual value 2) you can extend that matchers so that you can add more "verbs" to Hamcrest like you could add to make it `assertThat(  Math.pow( 2, 3 ),  is(relativelyPrimeTo( 49 ))  );`

Answer (score -2):

Surely it makes logical sense to put the expected value first, as it's the first known value.

Think about it in the context of manual tests. A manual test will have the expected value written in, with the actual value recorded afterwards.

Comment: "logical sense"?  The phrase "I expect the answer to the question 'what is the meaning of life?' to equal 42" is organized logically, making logical sense.

Comment: Yes, the sentence is arranged correctly. I'm talking more about the concept of an expectation. An expectation comes logically first. Look at the definition of expectation from Google:

"a strong belief that something will happen or be the case."

*will* happen. i.e. it will happen *after* the expectation is set.

Comment: No, it doesn't.