# Unit test case for If condition

Tags: c#

I have a  method `IsValid`:

```
public void IsValid(string applicationNumber)
{
    if (!applicationNumber.Length.Equals(15))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("De lengte van de rubriek: aanvraagnummer [001.], met waarde {0}, is niet valide.", applicationNumber));
    } else {
        applicationNumberExpression = "qwerty123456789";

        if (!applicationNumberExpression.IsMatch(applicationNumber))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Het aanvraagnummer [001.] met waarde {0} is niet conform de voorgeschreven structuur.", applicationNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

I try to write a unit test case for `isvalid`, but i get some errors.

```
public void IsValidTestApplicationNumber()
{
    var appno1 = new MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectModel.ApplicationNumber();

    MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectModel.ApplicationNumber appno = new 
    MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectStore.ApplicationNumber();

    string applicationNumber = "qwerty123456789";

    Assert.AreSame(appno.IsValid(applicationNumber);//error in thisline "no overload for method takes one argument"
}
```

Comment: Fix your code and ask a question.

Comment: I, too, have a method.

Comment: how to fix my code i am new to stack overflow

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have to write Unit test case for IsValid() method. i wrote test method but i am getting error

Comment: @mjwills no i doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest_MailClient
    {

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsValid_TestApplicationNumber()
    {

        MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectModel.ApplicationNumber appno = new MFA.Convana.BusinessLayer.ObjectStore.ApplicationNumber();

        String Input;
        String exception;
        String TestCase;

        XMLHelper TestData = new XMLHelper();
        TestCase = TestData.GetTestDataString("IsValid");
        String[] arr = TestCase.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (arr.Length > 0 && TestCase.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Input = arr[i].Substring(0, arr[i].IndexOf(TestData.FieldDelimiter));
                exception = arr[i].Substring(arr[i].IndexOf(TestData.FieldDelimiter) + 3);
                try
                {
                    appno.IsValid(Input);
                    Assert.IsTrue(true);                           
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                  Assert.AreEqual(exception, ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.Inconclusive("Test Skipped as no test data");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary mistake is attempting to assert on a function that returns void. This isn't possible.

You have two options:

a) Leave `IsValid` as returning void, and replace:

```
Assert.AreSame(appno.IsValid(applicationNumber);
```

with:

```
appno.IsValid(applicationNumber);
```

**OR**

b) Change `IsValid` to return a `bool`. To do this, change:

```
Assert.AreSame(appno.IsValid(applicationNumber);
```

to either:

```
Assert.IsTrue(appno.IsValid(applicationNumber));
```

(depending on what you want the test to do)

Also, change:

```
public void IsValid(string applicationNumber)
{
    if (!applicationNumber.Length.Equals(15))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("De lengte van de rubriek: aanvraagnummer [001.], met waarde {0}, is niet valide.", applicationNumber));
    } else {
        applicationNumberExpression = "qwerty123456789";

        if (!applicationNumberExpression.IsMatch(applicationNumber))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Het aanvraagnummer [001.] met waarde {0} is niet conform de voorgeschreven structuur.", applicationNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
public bool IsValid(string applicationNumber)
{
    if (!applicationNumber.Length.Equals(15))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("De lengte van de rubriek: aanvraagnummer [001.], met waarde {0}, is niet valide.", applicationNumber));
    } else {
        applicationNumberExpression = "qwerty123456789";

        if (!applicationNumberExpression.IsMatch(applicationNumber))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Het aanvraagnummer [001.] met waarde {0} is niet conform de voorgeschreven structuur.", applicationNumber));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I cant change " void to bool " its other person code. they want test case for their code.

Comment: In that case, my option a) above covers that. Change that single line of code and away you go. _If that doesn't work, can you specify what exactly doesn't work about it?_

Answer (score 0):

> no overload for method takes one argument

Clearly error says everything ...
`Assert.AreSame(appno.IsValid(applicationNumber), /*TO WHAT SHOULD IT BE COMPARED*/);`

`Assert.AreSame(appno.IsValid(applicationNumber), false);`

**EDIT :**
*Extending this answer to be more accurate and on topic.*

You're trying to compare two values but using reference comparer ( `Assert.AreSame` ).

This can fail because the 2 references are not the same ( [read about references here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx) ).

What you should do is to compare the two **values**. To do this you have to use different assertion methods.

For your example you can use `Assert.IsTrue` if you expect your method to return `true` or `Assert.IsFalse` if your expected value is `false`:

```
bool result = meObj.IsValid("someString");
// let's say you're expecting false
Assert.IsFalse(result);
// but if you're expecting true then change IsFalse to IsTrue
```

Or you can use `AreEqual` which in your case will be `Assert.AreEqual<bool>` :

```
bool result = meObj.IsValid("someString");
bool expected = false;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
```

Comment: If you do want to use `AreSame`, the `false` should be the first parameter rather than the second. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243766.aspx

Comment: please tell how to write test case for this method i am totally wrong..

Comment: That's just naming, `Assert.AreSame(expected, actual)` but order has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @m.rogalski Run these tests (https://dotnetfiddle.net/csu6jo) locally and see how the error messages differ. Yes - they will both fail under the same conditions. But putting the parameters in the wrong order will give a very misleading message. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331259/unit-testing-why-is-the-expected-argument-always-first-in-equality-tests .

Comment: That's why you have an overload method `AreSame(object, object, string);`... Still don't get your point. These methods are used to compare values/references so it's not a must to keep them in either left or right side.

Comment: But it cannot implicitly convert type void to bool

Comment: please see my answer