# Why does xUnit Assert.Equal function expect the actual value as second argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

XUnit is a fantastic tool for unit testing, I use it extensively in every .NET Project.

But, I still don't get why in the Assert.Equal function, the "expected" value is supposed to come first. Not doing it triggers a warning in the code.

Actually, it sounds more natural to say : I want to check *this car* and it's expected to be *red*, than the opposite *red* should bethe color of *that car*.

Furthermore, if you pass the object as first argument, the autocompletion gives you logical value for the actual parameter : in the example below, *cache.APIConnectionStatus* is an Enum, and autocomplete triggers a dropdown with all potential Enum values when writing down the assertion, which speeds up considerably the writing process.

Is there any logical reason for having the opposite?

I know this is a detail and there are many ways to disable warnings / write an extension overriding the Equal method, but in the end it looks a bit messy and/or time consuming every time I start a new project.

[image]

Comment: This is probably a question you should direct at the XUnit developers rather than Stack Overflow. Although I share your opinion on the matter.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi you're right but I didn't want to raise an issue on GitHub before having a feedback from the community :)

Comment: I'm struggling to find a unit testing framework that *doesn't* follow this convention (if it uses `Equal` style asserts). It may not have been an explicit decision made by the xUnit developers other than "let's follow the normal conventions"

Comment: In fact, someone asked [why this convention existed in *every* test framework back in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331259/unit-testing-why-is-the-expected-argument-always-first-in-equality-tests)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well spotted, this is actually the same question. Thanks! So bottom line, this is a legacy from old languages but this is less natural and  a source of never ending confusion :-)

Comment: As one answer said, if you were manually running through a table of tests it's not unusual for the headings, in order, to be along the lines of `Action, Expected Result, Actual Result` where the first two are already pre-filled and the last one filled in as the test is performed.

Comment: You could also use Assert.IsTrue(ActualValue == ExpectedValue) if you feel it's more natural (and I agree it does).

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi yes that's what I do, but I get a Resharper/Visual Studio warning which tells me to use Assert.Equal instead ! So, it's like swapping one warning for another...

Comment: @XavierAM: Note that `Assert.IsTrue` like that means you get much less useful information if the assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, knowing which of the two values is the expected value helps in generating an error message: *Expected x, actual value y*. So it makes sense that the two parameters are in a fixed order.

Secondly, why would you put the expected value first? It's totally arbitrary of course, but consider these lines:

```
Assert.Equal(5, myTestObject.SomeProperty);
Assert.Equal(6, myTestObject.SomeOtherProperty);
Assert.Equal(2, myTestObject.SomePropertyObject.SomeProperty);
Assert.Equal(6, myTestObject.SomePropertyObject.SomeOtherProperty);
```

For me (but of course, that is personal) that is more readable than the alternative:

```
Assert.Equal(myTestObject.SomeProperty, 5);
Assert.Equal(myTestObject.SomeOtherProperty, 6);
Assert.Equal(myTestObject.SomePropertyObject.SomeProperty, 2);
Assert.Equal(myTestObject.SomePropertyObject.SomeOtherProperty, 6);
```

Comment: I completely agree with you on the fixed order, that was not my point. And for the readability I completely disagree :-D .I prefer the second option (and I'd get the autocompletion if it was not an int) but as you say, it's totally arbitrary if there is no technical reason behind this order.